# How to match part of a field with data in another field with query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables table1 and table2:

- table1 contains a field named `id` with a value `1212` (example) in it.
- table2 has a field named `action` with a data like `added 1212` or `updated 1212`.

Now check this query.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.name
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t2.action LIKE 'added t1.id'
```

I want to add the `name` field in the second table, to first one with the `added`(`updated` not needed) data only.
What is the where clause for this condition?
How can I query this?

Comment: `LIKE ('added ' || t1.id)`?  I'm not sure of the relative precedence of LIKE vs `||` so I'd use the parentheses to be sure.

Comment: not working.
returned empty.
:(

Comment: You should never store two pieces of data in one field.  `'added'` should be in its own field, and `1212` should be stored in another field.  It then becomes easy to write the query *(See @xdazz answer)* but you can also easily apply constraints, foreign keys, and all sort of other relational database constructs.  Your structure is bad practice, the proposed structure in the answer is standard practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it like this.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.name
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t1.id = (RIGHT(t2.action, 4)) AND t2.action LIKE 'added %'
```

thanks to all who tried to help me.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to divide `action` column to two columns, one for action type, and one for action target. Then you could join the two tables.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.name
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.action_target
WHERE t2.action_type = 'added'
```

Comment: Unknown column 't2.action_type' in 'where clause'

Comment: @KrishnaRajK I suggested you change you db design, if you didn't change, of cause there is no `t2.action_type` :)